# Delete Specific Rows from Excel from a List of Row Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, power-query

I have a worksheet with 83,188 rows and 4 columns of data.

I have another worksheet that has a list of row numbers (eg 18751, 9127, 696, and etc) that signify the rows I would like to delete from the 83,188 x 4 worksheet.

These row numbers were found using the =XMATCH() formula + Paste Values.

In total there are 1,746 unique row numbers that I would like to delete from the 83,188 x 4 columns worksheet.

Is there a way to use VBA to delete these 1,746 rows? If not VBA, another possible solution to select all these rows and delete them?

Note: If VBA were to delete row 18751 and etc would this shift cause the remainder of my row numbers to be incorrect as the 83,188 x 4 data becomes 83187 x 4?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I didn't quite understand what values you were looking for using the =XMATCH() formula. Perhaps this was an additional step that could be dispensed with. Tell us more about your task - which lines did you want to remove? Duplicates? Some list of excluded values?

Comment: @JohnSUN I should've mentioned that. I used XMATCH() to match ID values from a Control File to the 83,188 x 4 data. XMATCH returned the row numbers of the matches in the 83,188 x 4 data. These are the 1,746 unique rows I am trying to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to make this work. One of the simplest:

1. Add a fifth column to the data sheet with a heading, for example, "Order" and a formula like
   `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet_with_row_numbers!$A$1:$A$1746;ROW());"";ROW())`

For rows to be deleted, the cells will remain empty. For other rows, the cell will have its row number.

2. Replace the formulas in this column with its result (for example, copy and paste special - values)
3. Sort the table in ascending order of the values ​​in the "Order" column.
4. Go to the end of your table and look again at the rows that ended up at the very bottom. If the rows that are to be deleted are selected, then delete them
5. Remove the auxiliary column "Order"

Comment: Thank you @JohnSUN